# Testing custom QGIS plugins

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am rewritting a custom QGIS application as a plugin for QGIS. I am testing it by writing some new code, then deactivate/activate the plugin in the plugin manager, which seems to me a bit cumbersome.

Is there a way to reload the plugin faster?

Comment: `Plugin Reloader` plugin?

Comment: Its probably also best practice to decouple as much code from QGIS as possible, and write test wrappers and create any mock objects you need so you can run your plugin code without a full QGIS running... But maybe you do this already?

Comment: Agree with your comment as far as bussiness logic goes. Im just checking to see how to integrate/modify certain GUI parts into QGis, so i had the need to constantly reload it to see the relevant changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Nathan W answer in comments is correct. You need to use the **Plugin reloader**. This useful plugin does exactly what your looking for.

Just go in the Plugins menu/Manage and install plugins/Not installed/Plugin Reloader.

[image: Plugin reloader]

It'll add a new menu and you'll be able to reload a plugin with F5 key

[image: Plugin reloader menu]

As a bonus in your workflow, you might be interested to create your own repository on a common server (to share your plugin internally) :

[image: Plugin rep]

With an XML file looking like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<plugins>
  <pyqgis_plugin version="1.0" name="My Plugin">
    <description>this my personnal plugin</description>
    <homepage>//mysrv/Plugins/</homepage>
    <file_name>myplugin.zip</file_name>
    <author_name>My and myself</author_name>
    <download_url>//mysrv/Plugins/myplugin.zip</download_url>
    <qgis_minimum_version>2.8</qgis_minimum_version>
    <experimental>true</experimental>
  </pyqgis_plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: For a second i thought Nathan made a joke there, because i couldn't find the Reloader plugin. In 2.16 it is listed under "experimental" and i had that ticked out in the listing. Thanks for the help!